# Limitations when adding new users

Tags: users

I began adding new users to my site tonight, all as authors. Is there a limitation to the number of users or how quickly they are added, after adding the 50th user there seems to be a minute or two delay before wordpress will allow me to add the next user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't have any real limitation to that although your `wp_users` table may not be optimized and the queries to it become slow. Try doing this:

1. **Repair and optimize** your tables
2. **Add Indexes** to frequently used columns such as `user_login` or `user_nicename` and play around until it speeds everything up a bit

You may also try **disabling plugins** one by one just in case there is a badly coded WP hook/action.

As a final solution, I would add a huge list of users **directly through a SQL query**, that way you can add thousands of them in less than a second.